# jQuery: Main nav items selected depending on URL or page name

Tags: jquery

Ok, I've looked all over for a solution for this but so far I'm unable to find anything related to what I need to accomplish.

What I need is very simple as far as logic goes.

I have a nav bar like this one:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="download.shtml">Download</a></li>
       <li><a href="documentation.shtml">Documentation</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.shtml">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.shtml">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the URLs of the site are straightforward:

```
http://domain.net/download.shtml
http://domain.net/documentation.shtml
http://domain.net/contact.shtml
http://domain.net/about.shtml
```

**Question:**

How can I detect which page/URL I'm on and add a class of `.active` to the corresponding nav item?

The end result would be, for example if I'm in the Download page:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="download.shtml" class="active">Download</a></li>
       <li><a href="documentation.shtml">Documentation</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.shtml">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.shtml">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, by checking anchor href `indexOf` in `location.href`

```
$(function(){
    $.each($("nav a"), function(){
       var self = $(this);
       if(location.href.indexOf(self.prop('href'))>-1){
           self.addClass('active');
           //self.parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: `sibling()` is actually `siblings()` and in this case the anchors have no siblings, instead it's the `<li />`s that are siblings. You won't need to remove the class however because the classes won't persist between page loads.

Comment: P.S. You can run .each() directly after the selectors, so `$("nav a").each(function() {})`. A little bit easier to read in my mind but could be a preference ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.location.pathname if your urls are that simple. For example:

```
$(function(){
  $('nav a').each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr('href') === window.location.pathname.substring(1) ){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/akevin/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Matthew but your suggestion didn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you link me to the page you're testing it on? I'd like to verify.

Comment: I do see the link is red, but there's no way to make a true test since the other links, of course, don't work. When I click on other links there's no 'real' page, of course. But then I refresh or click your link again and I don't see the top link styled in red anymore. Not sure what's going on. Thanks a lot for your time and persistance, gave you a vote.